# How to resolve: Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I've googled and read through a number of sites, including most of the related articles here at stackoverflow and I can't figure out how to get around the error:

***"Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process "***

**This server fails:**

- Apache 2.2.15
- mod_wsgi 4.4.13

**This server runs the same code without the truncated issue:**

- Apache 2.4.6
- mod_wsgi 3.4

Unfortunately, I don't have the option of upgrading Apache or downgrading mod_wsgi to get it to work. I've tried changing the header-buffer-size, but it doesn't seem to do anything (still fails):

http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html?highlight=truncated

> header-buffer-size=nnn Defines the maximum size that a response
>   header/value can be that is returned from a WSGI application. The
>   default size is 32768 bytes. This might need to be overridden where
>   excessively large response headers are returned, such as in custom
>   authentication challenge schemes which use the WWW-Authenticate
>   header.

Any thoughts about how to fix this?

**Chrome Dev Tools output:**

**Response Headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Date: Wed, 07 Jun 2017 11:49:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Content-Length: 644 Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Request Headers view
source
```

**Request Headers:**

```
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic 999999ZXQ0Myo=
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:removed.the.url.for.security
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://removed.the.url.for.security/TeamStats/provstats/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

**Edited wsgi_ssl.conf file:**

```
#get warning, already loaded
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
LDAPVerifyServerCert off
LDAPSharedCacheSize 500000
LDAPCacheEntries 1024
LDAPCacheTTL 600
LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
LDAPOpCacheTTL 600
LDAPConnectionTimeout 5

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    TimeOut 120

    ServerName server.name.address:443
    ServerAdmin admin@address.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
      nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
      downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/cert.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.pem

    LogLevel error
    CustomLog /var/log/access_log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/error_log

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/documents
    <Directory /var/www/html/documents>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    AddType text/html .php
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthName "test name"
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on

        AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://address and parameters here"

        AuthLDAPBindDN "parameters here"
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        AuthLDAPBindPassword password
        AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute sAMAccountName

        SSLRequireSSL
        Satisfy any
        #Require valid-user
    </Location>

    WSGIDaemonProcess test display-name=test threads=25 header-buffer-size=65536 inactivity-timeout=300
    WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/test.wsgi process-group=test
    Alias /test/static /var/www/html/documents/test/static
    <Location /test>
        WSGIProcessGroup test
        Require ldap-user "username"
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**LogLevel set to info:**

```
[Thu Jun 08 11:33:58 2017] [info] [client 0.0.0.0] mod_wsgi (pid=33568, process='test', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/test.wsgi'.
[Thu Jun 08 11:34:07 2017] [error] [client 0.0.0.0] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'test': /var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/test.wsgi, referer: https://url.address.net/test/
```

Comment: Did you try setting ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`` as most answers should have suggested, given that primary reason is the daemon process crashing. Ensure you have ``LogLevel`` in Apache set to ``info`` at least as then mod_wsgi will log more about why processes may be restarting.

Comment: Hi Graham, yes that was one of the first things I tried.  I'll post my apache wsgi.conf in my original post after I get it cleaned up.. maybe there's something I'm missing or in the wrong spot.  Thank you for responding!

Comment: I added both the wsgi_ssl.conf for apache and the LogLevel after setting it to info.

Comment: When using ``info`` for ``LogLevel``, was there anything after the message about truncated or oversized response headers from mod_wsgi about processes restarting? Did the process with ``pid`` given in the log file still exist? If you have a site wide log file as well as virtual host specific log files for Apache, check the site wide log file.

Comment: I was able to get this resolved.  I start combing through code and found a pandas groupby statement that was causing the truncated error for some reason.  There were a few rows in the dataframe that didn't want to group to a 0 value. I filtered those out and it worked. I didn't expect to see a truncated error with type of issue, so it took me down the wrong road to troubleshoot.  Graham, thank you for your help, sorry to have wasted your time!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use aws EC2 and eb server, and the same error message showed up. After detailed check, I found that this is just simple memory error. When I scale up my instance, the problem solved.

From [official page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html), To configure EC2 instances in the Elastic Beanstalk console:

1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
2. Navigate to the management page for your environment.
3. Choose Configuration.
4. On the Instances configuration card, choose Modify

I have tried method listed above to solve the problem, add following code in 03_scipy.config file and save it to .ebextension directory. However, it doesn't work.

```
container_commands:  
  AddGlobalWSGIGroupAccess: 
    command: "if ! grep -q 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' ../wsgi.conf ; then echo 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' >> ../wsgi.conf; fi;"
```